# psycopg2 SyntaxError with time or date

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I have a code that automatically identifies for what table, which columns and what the values to parse into sql insert statement. It works well with all of my tables, except only one. This is a structure of the model of this table:

```
class HourlyForecast(Model, db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'hourly_forecast'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
city_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('city.id'), nullable=False)
weather_status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('weather_status.id'), nullable=False)
temperature = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
wind_speed = db.Column(db.Float(decimal_return_scale=2), nullable=False)
pressure = db.Column(db.Float(decimal_return_scale=2), nullable=False)
humidity = db.Column(db.Float(decimal_return_scale=2),  nullable=False)
precipitation = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
time = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
current_time = db.Column(db.Time, nullable=False)
date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
```

I got SyntaxError only with this table.
My insertion statement:

```
columns = kwargs.keys()
values = [kwargs[column] for column in columns]
insert_statement = f'insert into {table}(%s) values %s'
obj = cur.mogrify(insert_statement, (AsIs(','.join(columns)), tuple(values)))
```

This is an error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: ПОМИЛКА:  синтаксична помилка в або поблизу "current_time"
LINE 1: ...e,wind_speed,pressure,humidity,precipitation,time,current_ti...
```

It's says in Ukrainian `syntax error at or near "current_time"`.
And this values were parsed into the `hourly_weather` table:

```
[5, 1, 16, 2, 1018, 61, 4, 8, '08:34', datetime.date(2022, 6, 16)]
```

Where `current_time` is **before** the **last** one value.

And yes, I use both psycopg2 and sqlalchemy. There are some reasons for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure I follow all that is going on here (actually, I’m sure that I don’t...) but I think that

1. Your issue is that [`current_time` is a keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) in PostgreSQL, and
2. that you should probably use the [SQL building features](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier) of psycopg2 to handle the necessary quoting for you.

Comment: Thank you! It was really because of keyword.